# How do I migrate from Ubuntu to Debian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, migration

I've been considering migrating my laptop from Ubuntu to Debian.  I didn't set up a separate home partition.  Is it as easy as just installing Debian over Ubuntu?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First thing first, move that home directory to a new partition.  It's really not that difficult to do (I made the same mistake, took ~30 min to do, most of it copying).  I'll give you a simple step-by-step, but more [detailed walkthroughs](http://www.go2linux.org/how-to-move-home-directory-to-another-partition) [are available](http://www.google.com/search?q=ubuntu+move+home+to+a+new+partition).

1. Create a new ext3/ext4 (or other fs) partition on a drive (eg /dev/sda3) in gparted.
2. Mount the new drive:

   - `sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/disk`
3. Copy the entire contents of your /home directory to the new drive.  There is some debate whether to use `rsync` or `cp` for this, but `cp` worked fine for me (using the `-a` flag as nagul pointed out to maintain file permissions and ownership).

   - `sudo cp -a /home /media/disk`
4. Edit your `/etc/fstab` file and create a new entry for `/dev/sda3` and set its mount point as `/home`.
5. Move your existing home directory (don't delete it yet in case something goes wrong).

   - `sudo mv /home /home_old`
6. Now you can either unmount and remount `/dev/sda3` to `/home` or just reboot the computer.

After you have /home on its own parition, changing your distro is incredibly simple.  Just download a live cd and/or an installation disk for the distribution you want and install it on the same partition hosting your current distro (or on a seperate partition for multi-boot purposes).

Then, after you have the distro installed, just follow steps 4-6 again (if the options for a custom `/home` partition weren't available in the installer).  Now you have all your old files, settings, etc but with a brand new shiny distro.

Comment: You should investigate using `cp -a` if you want to retain permissions and ownership info.

Comment: OR, move the /home directory to a different physical drive, which is what I do.

Answer (score 2):

An over-the-top upgrade will not work.

Before you do anything else, backup your data (though that should go without saying).

Then you could:

1. Make space for a new install by shrinking and moving partitions
2. Install Debian in the newly freed space
3. Once setup mount the old partition somewhere and make `/home` a synlink to `/home` on the old partition.
   (note: file/dir ownerships will be wrong, as users will not have the same UIDs nor groups the same GIDs, you'll need to adjust them or mess around to make the UID->user and GID->group relations the same on the new setup as the old)

or

1. Wipe the system
2. Install fresh
3. Restore `/home` from backup
   (you may still need to mess with file/dir ownership)